# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com/ibm/ws/ssl/core/Constants.ALL_PROTOCOLS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere-8

I am getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com/ibm/ws/ssl/core/Constants.ALL_PROTOCOLS while trying to create a jms Connection from the ConnectionFactory. Googled a lot but did not find a proper solution. Are some jars missing? I have configured the JMS resources in Websphere Application Server 8. I have already added -

```
com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.0.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.messagingClient.jar
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.client_ExpeditorDRE_8.0.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.0.0.jar
com.ibm.xml.thinclient_8.0.0.jar
```

PFB my code and stack trace:

```
package com.jms.test;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    System.out.println("Start.....");
    Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2810");
    //String pUrl = System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
    //System.out.println("*******"+pUrl+"********");
    InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext(environment);
    System.out.println("Init Done");

    QueueConnectionFactory qConFac =  (QueueConnectionFactory)initContext.lookup("jms/queueConnectionFactory");
    System.out.println("Connection Factory is - "+qConFac.toString());

    Queue queue = (Queue) initContext.lookup("jms/inQueue");
    System.out.println("Queue is - "+queue.toString());

    initContext.close();
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    Message message = null;

    try {
        connection = qConFac.createConnection();
        /*session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        connection.start();
        message = consumer.receive();
        System.out.println("Message received is "+message.toString());*/
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //System.out.println("JMS Exception while creating connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}

Start.....
Init Done
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:31 AM null null
SEVERE: security.JSAS1480I
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
INFO: Client code attempting to load security configuration
Connection Factory is - com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueConnectionFactoryImpl@fd4c0ee4
Queue is - queue://inQueue?busName=server1_bus
Nov 14, 2014 9:21:32 AM null null
INFO: ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I
Exception in thread "P=91001:O=0:CT" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:  com/ibm/ws/ssl/core/Constants.ALL_PROTOCOLS
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.FIPSUtils.getProtocolTypes(FIPSUtils.java:268)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager.getSSLProtocolForFipsLevel(SSLConfigManager.java:3619)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.provider.AbstractJSSEProvider.getSSLContextInstance(AbstractJSSEProvider.java:913)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.provider.IBMJSSE2Provider.getSSLContextInstance(IBMJSSE2Provider.java:65)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.provider.AbstractJSSEProvider.generateNewSSLContext(AbstractJSSEProvider.java:203)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.provider.AbstractJSSEProvider.getSSLContext(AbstractJSSEProvider.java:189)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.provider.AbstractJSSEProvider.getSSLSocketFactory(AbstractJSSEProvider.java:893)
at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper.getSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:21)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.framework.impl.ThinClientTransportFactory.<init>(ThinClientTransportFactory.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.framework.impl.ThinClientTransportFactory.<clinit>(ThinClientTransportFactory.java:98)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.framework.impl.ThinClientFramework.getNetworkTransportFactory(ThinClientFramework.java:66)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.octracker.OutboundConnectionTracker.connect(OutboundConnectionTracker.java:549)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.jfapchannel.impl.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.connect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:132)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.comms.client.ClientSideConnection.connect(ClientSideConnection.java:233)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.contactBootstrapService(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:691)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.remoteBootstrap(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createCoreConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:711)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createCoreConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:647)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:376)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:162)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135)
at com.jms.test.Demo.main(Demo.java:41)
```

Comment: That usually happens when the versions of your jar files don't match (meaning you have the jar file, but it is too old or too new). Do you have 8_0_0 for all the websphere stuff?

Comment: yes... will this require some other jars?

Comment: Remove from the classpath `com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar` and `com.ibm.ws.sib.client_ExpeditorDRE_8.0.0.jar` jars.

Comment: Ok. How would removing `com.ibm.ws.sib.client_ExpeditorDRE_8.0.0.jar` help? What problem is this jar causing?